# Jsp loading image from webapps ROOT folder

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets

I am working on a Java application and what I want to do is to give to the users the functionality to upload an image and view it at their profile. I know similar questions have been answered many many times but this is my first time doing this and I am really struggling to make it work.

So this is my testing code:

**upload.jsp**

```
...
<body>
    <form method="post" action="FileUploader" encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" value="select images..."/>
        <input type="submit" value="start upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
...
```

**FileUploader.java**

As you can see here, I store all my images in Tomcat's `webapps/ROOT/files` folder.

```
@WebServlet("/FileUploader")
public class FileUploader extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
            out.println("Nothing to upload");
            return; 
        }
        FileItemFactory itemfactory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemfactory);
        try{
            List<FileItem>  items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(request));
            for(FileItem item:items){

                String contentType = item.getContentType();
                if(!contentType.equals("image/png")){
                    out.println("only png format image files supported");
                    continue;
                }
                File uploadDir = new File("/home/agg/apache-tomcat/webapps/ROOT/files");
                File file = File.createTempFile("img",".png",uploadDir);
                item.write(file);

                out.println("Filename: " + file.getName());
                out.println("File Saved Successfully");

                response.sendRedirect("message.jsp");
            }
        }
        catch(FileUploadException e){
            out.println("upload fail");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("can't save");
        }
    }
}
```

**message.jsp**

Here, I am trying to load one of the images saved through another servlet.

```
...
<body>
    <img src="file/img1.png">
</body>
```

**FileServlet.java**

Servlet that retrieves the image.

```
@WebServlet("/file/*")
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
    private String filePath;

     public void init() throws ServletException {
        this.filePath = "/files";
    }

    protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("================In do get==================");

        // Get requested file by path info.
        String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println("Requested File: " + requestedFile);

        // Check if file is actually supplied to the request URI.
        if (requestedFile == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file object.
        File file = new File(filePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Filename: " + file.getName());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

        // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("DOES NOT EXIST");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

    // more code here but it does not matter
    }
}
```

The problem is that the image does not load. The path printed at the console seems to be correct. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For me your problem is here

```
<img src="file/img1.png">
```

It doesn't seem to be the correct path for the next reasons:

1. The root directory is `/.../webapps/ROOT/files` so it should start with `files` not `file`.
2. The name of the file should be `img` + a random long + `.png` here you set the random long to 1 which doesn't seem to be correct
3. As it is in the ROOT webapp, you should rather put an absolute path instead of a relative path, in other words the path should start with a slash